# An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=3):

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos, dart

Trying to run this project on a MacBook but this error keeps showing. Looked for some solutions but they all failed.
I am working on Flutter project.
The code was built on a different MacBook.

That's the whole error:

***Exception: Unable to launch com.projectname.client on 9CE7CA53-67B5-442B-AA2C-35A19A42CEEF:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=3):
The request to open "com.bringitback.client" failed.
The process did launch, but has since exited or crashed.
Command: xcrun simctl launch 9CE7CA53-67B5-442B-AA2C-35A19A42CEEF com.bringitback.client --enable-dart-profiling --enable-checked-mode --verify-entry-points --start-paused --observatory-port=0
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.***

Comment: hii. did you find any solution?

Comment: @Yasha i opened xcode and: Product -> clean build folder and then i built it again and it worked for me.please let me know if it worked for you too

Comment: Sure, I will check & let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it worked just fine on a real iPhone, but I had the same issue when I tried to run it on the iOS Simulator on my Mac with M2.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727818) I found that this might happen when Rosetta is not installed. So, after executing the command below in the terminal, I was able to run my app on the iOS Simulator as well.

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```